# unique_ptr alternative for dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, unique-ptr

I wrote a class that has to interface with some old code that requires a few C-style arrays (or at least the pointer to the first element) as arguments.

These arrays are members of my class and they are particularly large (50kb) so I want to put them on the heap so that the objects of my class are not huge on the stack. I'm a big believer of using resource managing objects so I would rather not manage these arrays on the heap myself.

I've found using unique_ptr's for this works particularly well. For example:

`std::unique_ptr<SOMETYPE[]> someArrayName`

and using:

`someArrayName(new SOMETYPE[someLargeSize])`

in the initialization list for my constructor. This allows me to use these as regular C arrays using the `.get()` method for functions that need that as arguments and I don't have to manage the memory myself. But I just realized my co-worker (the one who actually compiles our code for releases) is still on VS2008, obviously lacking support for C++0x features like `unique_ptr`. First, is my current solution using unique_ptr's for this a good one? If so, is there a replacement for this to maintain all the behavior I need in something like boost?

Comment: What about `std::vector`? (and you can pass along `&v[0]` to the legacy interface)

Comment: `std::vector` existed for this purpose and is older than C++11.

Comment: I agree I'm basically trying to emulate the pros of std::vector while maintaining compatibility with the functions the require pointers to arrays.

If I use std::vector, what is the best way to feed it in to something that wants a C style array?

EDIT: looks like @R.MartinhoFernandes suggested something for this I missed. Is using &v[0] the proper way to solve this then?

Comment: Boost's got `unique_ptr`, too.

Comment: @lanteau As R.MartinhoFernandes said, `&v[0]` (where `v` is a `std::vector`).

Comment: @lanteau: Yes, `&v[0]` is the proper way to solve this.  I wish there were a member function for it, but there isn't :(

Comment: @MooingDuck There is in C++11.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was apparently oblivious to the fact a vector can behave the way I needed. I was trying to emulate a vector in an overly complicated way it would see.

Comment: @MooingDuck Aren't you talking about &v.front()?

Comment: @Dilip: eh, that works too, though I've never seen that in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `std::unique_ptr` would require allocation using `new[]`.
Which is never (or almost never) the best solution.  In this
case, just use `std::vector`.  In pre-C++11, pass `&array[0],
array.size()`; in C++11, you can be clearer, and pass
`array.data(), array.size()`.  (This also has the advantage that
you don't have to special case empty vectors.)

Comment: @lanteau However you want.  You have more options than with `new[]`, but you can also do exactly what you would do with `new[]`, specifying the size, and then assigning to each element.

Comment: Thanks, this achieves the behavior I was looking for.